# Adding tags to the Zotero CSL Json export function

Tags: javascript, json

At the moment, Zotero (even version 5.0 beta) offers a decent CSL Json export, but it is still incomplete. Namely, the tags are not passed to the Json file. Metadata about bibliographic entries is very important because you can then use it to filter and categorise the Json output.

[This](https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/comment/268313) thread at the Zotero support forums says a hook can be added to the [translators file](https://github.com/zotero/translators/blob/master/CSL%20JSON.js#L68) (line 68):

```
function doExport() {
var item, data = [];
while(item = Z.nextItem()) data.push(ZU.itemToCSLJSON(item));
Z.write(JSON.stringify(data, null, "\t"));}
```

The tags (already in Zotero as item.tags) need to be passed on as an array. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Problem solved in the same thread. Add this function:

```
function doExport() {
var item, data = [];
while(item = Z.nextItem()) {
        var itemJSON = ZU.itemToCSLJSON(item);
        itemJSON.keyword = item.tags.map(o => o.tag).join(", ");
        data.push(itemJSON);
    }
Z.write(JSON.stringify(data, null, "\t"));
}
```